# inheritance in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance

Not real sure how to ask this question... Some of my terms may be incorrect but hopefully I'll be able to get the question across.  If I have a class something like this

```
Public Class Agency
  public property ID as integer=0
  public property Name as string=string.empty
  Public sub new()
  end sub
end class
```

and then a factory class that returns a list

```
Public Class Agency_Controller
  Public Sub New()
  end sub

 Public function Fetch() as list(of Agency)
  pop the list and return it
 end function
end class
```

If I create another class say Agency_Misc and want to inherit the Agency Class I get, how to do that?

```
Public Class Agency_Misc
 inherits Agency
 public property Address as string=string.empty
```

end class

Now if I want to use the Agency_Misc, how do I get the Agency_Controller Fetch function? In the code if I were going after the agency... I do something like
Dim oS as list(of Agency)=nothing
dim oC as new Agency_Controller
os=oc.Fetch()

but if I want my list to have the list(of Agency_Misc) (because I was doing some more stuff)
how do I do that.  I can't change list(of Agency) to list(of Agency_Misc) because it will tell me it can't convert it I think it was.

Anyway... I'd like to learn what it is I'm missing or what other approach I need to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined your classes properly, you can do the following:

Define a BaseClass. 
Define a DerivedClass which inherits from BaseClass

Define a List(Of BaseClass) and populate it with objects of DerivedClass (the List will accept objects of Dervived class, because these are, through inheritance, also objects of BaseClass.

Access the items in the list with a variable of Type DerivedClass.

What you CAN'T do is populate the list with objects of type BaseClass, and then attempt to access them using a variable of Type DerivedClass.

Ex. #1 THIS will work:

```
Public Class Form1
Private MyListOfBaseCLass As List(Of MyBaseClass)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MyListOfBaseCLass = New List(Of MyBaseClass)

    Dim dc As New MyDerivedCLass("City of Portland", "555 SW 5th Avenue")
    MyListOfBaseCLass.Add(dc)

    dc = New MyDerivedCLass("City of Salem", "222 E River Road")
    MyListOfBaseCLass.Add(dc)

    dc = New MyDerivedCLass("City of Denver", "333 SomeStreet")
    MyListOfBaseCLass.Add(dc)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each dc As MyDerivedCLass In MyListOfBaseCLass
        MsgBox(dc.MyName & ", " & dc.MyAddress)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

THIS will FAIL:

```
Public Class Form1
Private MyListOfBaseCLass As List(Of MyBaseClass)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MyListOfBaseCLass = New List(Of MyBaseClass)

    Dim dc As New MyBaseClass("City of Portland")
    MyListOfBaseCLass.Add(dc)

    dc = New MyBaseClass("City of Salem")
    MyListOfBaseCLass.Add(dc)

    dc = New MyBaseClass("City of Denver")
    MyListOfBaseCLass.Add(dc)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each dc As MyDerivedCLass In MyListOfBaseCLass
        MsgBox(dc.MyName & ", " & dc.MyAddress)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You best set the properties in the constructor

```
Public Class Agency

    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_ID = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private m_name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal name As String)
        Me.m_ID = id
        Me.m_name = name
    End Sub

End Class
```

...

```
  Dim HiDollar as New Agency(100, "High Dollar")
```